# Loss due to coupling between BEC and single particle state in superconductor

Tags: superconductivity

How come there is no loss due to coupling between the superconducting channel and the single particle channel?
I imaging the two channels being two parallel wires, so the magnetic field from the current running in the superconducting state, should fully inclose the single particle channel generating a electric field, that at least would create a displacement current and introduce a loss. Why is that not so?

Also is there no current fluctuation due to the current being carried by discrete charge quanta? I would assume that, that would also create a electric field fluctuation in the single particle channel causing a loss?